# Android 2.3.3 SQLite infinite loop

Tags: android, sqlite

In my project, I have 5 tables: Category, CategoryHasProduct, Product, StoreHasProduct and Store. There I store all my products, in which categories they are and in which store which product is available.

Now, I want to know how many products in all the categories are available, depending on which store is selected. For performance reasons, I want to use a SQL query for this. The query is

```
SELECT 
    count(*), 
    cp.category_id 
FROM 
    categoryhasproduct cp, 
    product p, 
    storehasproduct sp 
WHERE 
    p.sku = cp.product_id AND 
    sp.product_id = p.sku AND 
    sp.store_id = 2 AND 
    sp.isActive = 1  
GROUP BY cp.category_id
```

In the Project I use ORMLite. But to query this, I do a basic db-query

```
String query = "...";
SQLiteDatabase db = DBConnector.getConnector(context).getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
```

Now I have a problem, which makes no sense to me. On Android 4.0.3, everything works fine. The query takes something like 0.5 seconds to run and I can proceed. But when I try to execute the query on Android 2.3.3, the query itself seems to run into an infinite loop. Even after 20 minutes, the query is not finished. On a real device, the processor of the device is getting very hot, so it shuts himself down.

As I tried a little bit with the query, it seems that it is to large for sqlite on 2.3.3-devices. the concatenation with the last storehaseproduct-table seems to enlarge the query to much. I also tried other statements like nested queries or joins, but it seems that they have the same problem.

Does anybody else has observed such a strange behavior of sqlite? And the much more important question: what can I do to make this query work on Android 2.3.3 with a near equal runtime?

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow :-) Your query looks fine to me, I'm afraid, but hopefully someone'll be along who knows the differences in situation between sqlite on 2.3.3 and on 4.0.3...

Comment: Roughly how many rows have the tables `categoryhasproduct`, `product` and `storehasproduct`? Does the part of the where clause `sp.store_id = 2 AND sp.isActive = 1` reduce this number for the last table significantly? If so, maybe creating an intermediate temporary table with only the relevant rows and columns of `storehasproduct` may help.

Comment: Since I had also troubles with performing raw queries using SQLiteDatabase on older Android versions due to faulty transaction concurrency handling by the driver (it can just deadlock indefinitely), I want to ask you how you are performing your queries? You need to be careful from which thread you open the database and start a transaction and from which thread you query the database. That can cause troubles. If in doubt just try calling db.setLockingEnabled(false) after opening the connection (method is deprecated by now, but it still works for 2.3.3).

Comment: I'd add to @NobuGames`s comment - don't do all this stuff on a main thread use `AsyncTask`.

Comment: What is the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) for this on both devices?

Comment: categoryhasproducts contain around 16.500 rows. the clause `sp.store_id = 2 AND sp.isActive = 1` doesn't reduces the number for the last table by the factor 4, at the moment. The query is executed asynchronous, to show a loading spinner to the user, when the whole process runs.

Comment: If you open the database connection from the main UI thread this may also implicitly begin a transaction and give the UI thread ownership of that transaction. That in turn can result in a deadlock when you're trying to query the database from a different thread while that UI thread transaction is still open. You should try calling db.setLockingEnabled(false) right after opening. If your query works then you can at least know for sure that a "transaction concurrency deadlock" is to blame.

Comment: ok, after some testing, it seems that the query is just to intense for the system. `db.setLockingEnabled(false)` didn't worked. I also tried to put the query in the main thread, but it also didn't worked. Then I tried to compose the query table for table and it seems, that the query is to much work for Android 2.3.3. It seems, that the join with the `storehasproduct` table is to much. when I remove it, the query works, but will run for nearly 10 seconds. When I remove the `GROUP BY`, the result contains more than 6000 rows, that seems to be to much.

Comment: Try disabling ORMLite, and run with only one `SQLiteDatabase` instance in entire app.